# Calling Multiple Controller on a Route

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

Help me in a doubt, I have an application in laravel, and I would like to call several **Controller** in the same **Route**, is it possible?

I've tried it that way, but it does not work

```
$api->get('document', ['as' => 'system.api.manager.v1.document.listDoc1', 'shield' => ['system.manager.document.list'], 'any' => true, 'uses' => 'Doc1Controller@grid']);
$api->get('document', ['as' => 'system.api.manager.v1.document.listDoc2', 'shield' => ['system.manager.document.list'], 'any' => true, 'uses' => 'Doc2Controller@grid']);
$api->get('document', ['as' => 'system.api.manager.v1.document.listDoc3', 'shield' => ['system.manager.document.list'], 'any' => true, 'uses' => 'Doc3Controller@grid']);
```

Comment: Could you post these methods? Usually if this happens you could put the controller logic in a class (multiple methods) and make a new controller method which calls these methods

Comment: That won't work for obvious reasons. The Laravel router matches routes based on the path you've defined as the first parameter of the `get` method. Since you've defined the same path as `document` 3 times, you're essentially overriding the previous definition each time, so your code only matches the last one and executes the `Doc3Controller@grid`. To put this into perspective, consider you're trying to access that URL `https://yourdomain.com/document`. How could the Laravel router know if you mean to access the `listDoc1`, `listDoc2` or `listDoc3` route if the only reference is `/document`.

Comment: @PH27 Please provide some more context to what you're trying to achieve so people can offer an viable approach to solving this.

Comment: I came to leave the feedback, I got to do what I needed, I created a function in the Repository to return the data that I needed to be displayed on the grid, so I call only a function of the Controller in my route, which calls my function created in the Repository. Thank's guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance.
Define `GreatController` as parent of

`"Doc1Controller, Doc2Controller, Doc3Controller"`

then move your standart methods, functions to `GreatController`. I am doing that way. Also you can define all same methods in `_construct()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a closure instead a direct controller call. There you call your controller